# Use an iMac 5k or iMac 4k 2017 as a target display with Macbook Pro retina early 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac, thunderbolt, target-display

I have a Macbook Pro Retina early 2013 and I'd like to know if it's possible to use a brand new iMac 5K maybe the 4K 2017 as a target display for that macbook, is that possible, do I need an adapter from Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](https://appleinsider.com/articles/17/06/15/2017-4k-5k-imacs-wont-support-target-display-mode-despite-thunderbolt-3) on AppleInsider the 2017 4K and 5k iMacs do not support target display mode.

Comment: Thanks four your reply. So upset about the end of this support :(